# Building a project and a Spock test suite with gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy, spock

I'm trying to build a Springboot web application that creates a WAR and also a suite of tests using the Spock framework but every time I try to run `gradle build` the console will execute the tests but will not create the web app WAR although it mentions a file in the web app source code saying a deprecation warning so I know it is at least doing something with it. Is there some kind of configuration I'm missing from my `build.gradle` or concept about how `sourceSets` work? I can compile the web app fine and the tests when I do them separately with their own `build.gradle` files but I was hoping that the code below could build the WAR and execute the tests in the same file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'war'
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release'
    }

    maven {
        url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}

sourceSets{ 
            main { 
                 java { srcDir "src\\TestingWebAppSpringBoot\\src\\main\\java" }
                 resources {srcDir "src\\TestingWebAppSpringBoot\\src\\main\\resources" }
                 groovy { srcDirs = [] }   
            }

            test{
                groovy {
                    srcDirs = ["src\\test_pack\\com\\example\\diag\\test\\spock\\main", "src\\test_pack\\com\\example\\diag\\test\\spock\\test" ]
                }
            }
}

test{
    reports.html.destination = file("build\\spockTestResults")
    }

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.14'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    testCompile (
     fileTree(dir: 'build\\server\\_archives\\_release', include: '*.jar'),
     fileTree(dir: 'build\\common\\_archives\\_release', include: '*.jar'),
     'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.26',
     "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5",
     "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4"
    )

}

group = 'com.something.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Comment: This looks like a new project. Why are you trying to build it as a war? Additionally, while I'm not familiar with Gradle, nearly all Java tooling expects you to use `/` as a directory separator even on Windows.

Comment: The project is just a small web application quickly built to be used to test the functionality of a bigger project. The bigger project has a way of getting to this web app through a proxy. There is a Tomcat already used for these kind of web apps so I need the WAR instead of a JAR. The directory separator didn't do anything but thanks for letting me know about it. I didn't know that about Java tooling.

Comment: What was the reason to not use the default sourcesets?

Comment: The build.gradle is located outside of the project in the parent project so it can be called by a batch file. Maybe I need to define the web app project directory in gradle.settings or something instead of just defining the location of the main and resource. Any other suggestions or ways to go about the implementation besides just this one build file are welcome too. My first attempt was to do a multi project build  and have multiple build.gradle files but the test suite kept being built as a JAR instead of executing in the console.

Comment: It will probably be easier to take the more trodden path, and store the build file with the project, then call it in there by the batch file (if you have to use a batch file) 